# NSFetchRequest cause SIGABRT OR EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm using this simple code for my fetch request

```
NSArray *fetchResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

`NSLog(@" i want show my result : %@",fetchResults);` -> cause SIGABRT

If i'm using on my persistent store just after this creation, i have an error.

PS: the store was save between the populate and the request.

But if i close the app, and reopen ( in this case the store exist), i have no error.

in some case i can view this message : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

but i can't access to this exception.

if i count the fetch results, i have a good number, it's really strange.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok, i have found the problem !
In my populate code one of my relationShip was insert with an autorelease.
Supress this, and now it's OK.

I have forget this in core data ( don't use release, but set object to nil ) !

Comment: ok, but i must wait, because i'm "new user"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have found the problem!

In the populate code, one of my relationships was insert with an autorelease.

Remove this, and now it's OK.

This is not a good solution:

```
 NSManagedObject *relationEntity = [[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"picture" inManagedObjectContext:moc] autorelease];
```

Simply remove autorelease:

```
NSManagedObject *relationEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"picture" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

I have forgotten this in core data (**don't use release, just set object to `nil`**)!